# FCM not giving a high-priority notification (heads up notification)

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I've set my FCM Cloud Function to `priority: "high"` but it is still only giving a "default" priority notification (a sound + icon in the system tray).

I want a high priority where there is also a heads up notification like Facebook Messenger. Example below:

[image]

Here is my cloud function:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp();

exports.newMatch = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const user1token = data.user1token;
    const user2name = data.user2name;
    const user2 = data.user2;

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: user2name + " says hello!",
            body: "Test"
        },
        data: {
            "user2": user2,
        }
    }

    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 20000
    }

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(user1token, payload, options);
});
```

Is it possible to get a heads up notification?

PS: I'm using a Samsung S8 phone.

Comment: please Read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: I have but it seems the format of my cloud function (`node.js`) is a bit different to the format listed there. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Zorgan, were you able to find any solution to this?